# What is the required format for an Ajax GET response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arduino, ethernet

I am having a major problem trying to add an element to a response stream sent by an Arduino application in reply to an AJAX request. I have a message getting through successfully, but when I add an extra component to it, the message is not read. By monitoring the Ethernet traffic with Wireshark, I have determined that the additional element is not being completely terminated.

The code I am using is:

```
void SendTags(EthernetClient cl) {
  String value;      // stores value read from analog onputs
  int count;         // index for 'for' loops
  int str_length;
  char msg_chrs[0];

  Serial.println("Debug 395 - sending title and tags");
  cl.write("<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>\r\n");

  Str = "<app_data>\r\n";
  str_length = Str.length()+1;
  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
  cl.write(msg_chrs);

  Str = "<tags>\r\n";
  str_length = Str.length()+1;
  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
  cl.write(msg_chrs);

  for (count = 0; count < di_count; count++) {
    value = di_sig_tag[count];
    Str = "<DI_TAG>" + value + "</DI_TAG>\r\n";
    str_length = Str.length()+1;
    Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
    cl.write(msg_chrs);
 }

 //(similar code sections omitted for simplicity)

  Str = "</tags>\r\n";
  str_length = Str.length()+1;
  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
  cl.write(msg_chrs);

//  Str = "<title>\r\n";
//  str_length = Str.length()+1;
//  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
//  cl.write(msg_chrs);

//  Str = "<pr_name>" + pr_name + "</pr_name>\r\n";
//  str_length = Str.length()+1;
//  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
//  cl.write(msg_chrs);

//  Str = "</title>\r\n";
//  str_length = Str.length()+1;
//  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
//  cl.write(msg_chrs);

  Str = "</app_data>\r\n";
  str_length = Str.length()+1;
  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, str_length);
  cl.write(msg_chrs);

  Serial.println("Debug 462 - End of SendTags()");
}
```

In Wireshark, the elements being transmitted successfully are displayed using the HTTP protocol and are structured with one element per package, each package terminating in "\r\n" as expected.:

[image: HTML header for successful transmission]

If I enable the suspect code, the HTML header is:

[image: HTML header for failed transmission]

And the portion of the message with the relevant text is:

[image: TCP protocol showing added elements]

As you can see, the closing ">" and the terminating "\r\n" are not being transmitted. I have generated the inserted elements by cutting and pasting the successful elements and then editing as appropriate, and have also tried a number of permutations of `String` and `char[]` variables, all without success. But from the Wireshark trace the problem is between the Arduino code and the Ethernet link.

Any ideas or comments would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Check out this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_http_response.asp

Comment: @JeanPaul98 He is asking about sending the response from the server not how to handle the received response in JavaScript.

Comment: @JeanPaul98 The issue is that the response is not being transmitted faithfully from the server to Ethernet.  If I remove the suspect code, the message goes through and works as expected, with the values being displayed as required in the target.

Comment: `msg_chrs` array has the length of 0. How do you expect to put anything in it?

Comment: @gre_gor I'm initialising msg_chrs as zero length, then loading it with the Str.toCharArray statement.  I'm doing exactly the same thing with the preceding elements, and most of the offending elements are put out to Ethernet.

Comment: That's not how it works. `Str.toCharArray` doesn't change the length of the array. Writing outside of bounds is undefined behavior.

Comment: Can't you just write `Str` directly? `cl.write(Str);`?

Comment: @gre-gor (1) seems to work - I was under the impression that Str.toCharArray would put the required chars into the buffer (which is what is happening with the other elements). The whole thing is a candidate for a subroutine.

Comment: @gre_gor (2) Str and char[] give me a lot of strife so I try to keep to char[]

Answer (score -1):

For the record, (and anyone who might be interested), the working solution I have adopted is:

```
void SendTags(EthernetClient cl)
{
  String value;      // stores value read from analog onputs
  int count;         // index for 'for' loops
  int str_length;
  char msg_chrs[0];

  Serial.println("Debug 395 - sending title and tags");
  cl.write("<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>\r\n");
  cl.write("<app_data>\r\n");
  cl.write("<tags>\r\n");

  for (count = 0; count < di_count; count++)
  {
    value = di_sig_tag[count];
    Str = "<DI_TAG>" + value + "</DI_TAG>\r\n";
    ethWrite(Str, cl);
 }

  for (count = 0; count < do_var_count; count++)
  {
    value = do_sig_tag[count];
    Str = "<DO_TAG>" + value + "</DO_TAG>\r\n";
    ethWrite(Str, cl);
  }

    for (count = 0; count < ai_count; count++)
  {
    value = ai_sig_tag[count];
    Str = "<AI_TAG>" + value + "</AI_TAG>\r\n";
    ethWrite(Str, cl);
  }

  for (count = 0; count < ao_count; count++)
  {
    value = ao_sig_tag[count];
    Str = "<AO_TAG>" + value + "</AO_TAG>\r\n";
    ethWrite(Str, cl);
  }

  cl.write("</tags>\r\n");
  cl.write("<title>\r\n");

  Str = ("<PR_NAME>" + pr_name + "</PR_NAME>\r\n");
  ethWrite(Str, cl);

  cl.write("</title>\r\n");
  cl.write("</app_data>\r\n");

  Serial.println("Debug 462 - End of SendTags()");
}

void ethWrite(String st, EthernetClient cl)
{
  int st_length = st.length()+1;
  char msg_chrs[st_length];
  Str.toCharArray(msg_chrs, st_length);
  cl.write(msg_chrs);
}
```

So far, this is doing what I want and seems to be reasonably efficient coding.  Thanks to @gre-gor for comments - put me on the right track. My excuse is that I am working simultaneously in javascript (which does allow expanding arrays) and c++ (which doesn't).